# Dividing data by median of the data

Tags: data-transformation, median

I am reading a paper[1] and the authors wrote: "Finally, each column was divided by the median value of the corresponding column to remove systemic deviation"

My question is:
How does doing this median division help reducing systemic deviation?

[1]: Shahid Y. Khan, Muhammad Ali, Firoz Kabir, Santosh Renuse, Chan Hyun Na, C. Conover Talbot, Sean F. Hackett, S. Amer Riazuddin;
"Proteome Profiling of Developing Murine Lens Through Mass Spectrometry."
*Invest. Ophthalmol. Vis. Sci.* 2018; 59(1): 100-107.
doi: 10.1167/iovs.17-21601.
https://iovs.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2670138

Comment: Each variable now has median 1. Also, all variables are now dimensionless and unit-free. There are no other guarantees, but it's likely that variability is closer to similar than it was before.